# List Firebase database tables in spinner

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

I'm trying to list  my Firebase database tables in a spinner. I have te node Products that has a list of others in it. Myt goal is to list these sub catergies rom the parent node and list them in a spinner.
Have a look at my database.
[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvDYD.png)

This is what I have treid so far with little success.

```
mDatabaseReference.child("Products").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot data = dataSnapshot;
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot lists : data.getChildren()){
                Log.d("ddd","Array List: "+lists.getValue().toString());
                list.add(String.valueOf(lists.getValue()));
                //textView.setText(lists.getValue().toString());
            }
            showDataInSpinner(list);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

To display data in the Spinner, this is the code.

```
 public void showDataInSpinner(ArrayList<String> data) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data
    ); //Create the Adapter to set the data
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); //Set the layout resource to create the drop down views.
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter); //Set the data to your spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {

        @Override public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, String item) {
            category = item;

            refreshproducts();//displays db data
        }
    });

}
```

someone guide me on how to do it right.[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Ip5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `getValue()` use `getKey()` to get key of Node.

```
Log.d("ddd","Array List: "+lists.getKey().toString());
list.add(String.valueOf(lists.getKey()));
```